# How to Change DrawableLeft in Android Selector?

Tags: java, android, xamarin

How can I change the DrawableLeft image of a button using selectors?

I'm using the below selector file and a shape XML for drawable. When the button is clicked, the image doesn't change.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/toolbar_button_pressed"
          android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_selected" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/toolbar_button_pressed" 
          android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/ic_selected" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/toolbar_button_normal" />
</selector>
```

**toolbar_button_pressed**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
       android:shape="rectangle" >
    <corners android:radius="10dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/primary_dark" />
    <padding android:left="10dp"
             android:top="10dp"
             android:right="10dp"
             android:bottom="10dp" />
    <stroke  android:width="1dp"
             android:color="@color/divider" />
</shape>
```

**Layout Button**

```
<Button android:id="@+id/background_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btn_background"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_background"
        style="@style/ToolbarButton"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to solve this using selectors:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/style_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/style_button_text"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/toolbar_drawable_left"
        style="@style/ToolbarButton"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
```

**/res/drawable/toolbar_drawable_left.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/ic_about_highlight"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/ic_about_highlight"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_about" />
</selector>
```